# Is the function GetWordAt in S7.net wrong or Just RIGHT

Tags: c#, plc

As we can see in the following codes:

the function `GetWordAt` returns a short value from a `List<byte>` data, as we always do, it should be combine from two continuous bytes, but it is converted from ONE byte.

because I don't know the protocol of PLC S7 200 smart, I don't know it is wrong or just right.

The function is call only once by `public static void ParseResponse(byte[] message, int length, DataItem[] dataItems)` of `class S7WriteMultiple` in the program.

While the last function is by `public void Write(params DataItem[] dataItems)` of `class PLC` and its async version.

```cs
namespace S7.Net.Protocol
{
    internal static class Serialization
    {
        public static ushort GetWordAt(IList<byte> buf, int index)
        {
            return (ushort)((buf[index] << 8) + buf[index]);
        }
...
        public static void SetWordAt(ByteArray buffer, int index, ushort value)
        {
            buffer[index] = (byte)(value >> 8);
            buffer[index + 1] = (byte)value;
        }
```

Comment: What is your actual problem or question?

Comment: BTW, `ushort` is not a "word"

Comment: I mean if it should be return (ushort)((buf[index] << 8) + buf[index + 1]);

Comment: Yes, I believe it should be `buf[index+1]` - but that said, why not use `BitConverter` instead?

Comment: ushort is word, but in C# there is not type word

Comment: `ushort` is `UInt16` - it's only a _word size_ if you're using a 16-bit computer from the late-1980s (which you aren't...) - but you're not, so please avoid using names like that. ([While Win32's header files do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) _anachronistically_ have `#define WORD uint16_t` in them it doesn't apply in this context). Now, if those PLC S7 printers define a word as a 16-bit unsigned integer then you should document that in your code.

Comment: @Dai :The OP is receiving data from a Siemans Controller : PLC S7 200 smart so 16 bites may be correct.

Comment: @Dai word means something is two bytes, regardless of the system you are in. If ushort is 2 bytes, it is a word

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli _"word means something is two bytes"_ - not quite: [the term "word" or "word size" refers to the _natural unit of data_ in a given ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)), so it's only accurate to refer to a 16-bit value as "a word" in the context of a 16-bit ISAs. On modern x64 processors a "word" is at least 64-bits, and many processors have _internal word sizes_ of 128-bits or even 512-bits when you consider AVX-512 etc (though, _yes_, AVX-512's documentation _does_ refer to "doubleword" and "quadword" units, it's shorthand: AVX is not 16-bit.

Comment: Realize that the OP's code uses PROBLEM DOMAIN TERMINOLOGY, not IMPLEMENTATION domain.  A WORD in the PLC is a 16 bit value.  So WORD is correct.

Comment: Dear all, the question you discuss is out of the question I need the answer, that is to say whether the code below is right or not, I want to know why it get a ushort value from ONE byte but not from TWO bytes as we normaly do(return (ushort)((buf[index] << 8) + buf[index + 1]);):        ```public static ushort GetWordAt(IList<byte> buf, int index)
        {
            return (ushort)((buf[index] << 8) + buf[index]);
        }```